# How to store birthday through mailchimp API?

Tags: mailchimp

I'm using mailchimp 1.3 in a Codeigniter application through [this library](https://github.com/waynhall/CodeIgniter-Library-for-MailChimp-API-v1.3).

I have this piece of code:

```
$birthday = date('m/d', strtotime('1984-04-29');
echo $birthday;
$merge_vars = array(
'FNAME'=> $profile_info['name'], 
'LNAME'=> $profile_info['lastname'], 
'birthday' => $birthday,
'GROUPINGS' => array(array('name' => $this->group_name, 'groups' => $this->group1))
);

$this->mail_chimp->listSubscribe($this->list_id, $email, $merge_vars);
```

The subscription works and in the administration panel of mailchimp I can see the user name and lastname, but no birthday.

In the api documentation it says it should be formatted as MM/DD and echoing the
birthday I verified it was right.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score -3):

Ok, I solved.
I had to add a field for the birthday in the list settings as explained here:

http://kb.mailchimp.com/article/how-do-i-create-and-send-automatic-birthday-campaigns